# Elastic Image Slideshow Not Resizing Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slideshow

I am using Elastic Image Slideshow downloaded from here:

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ElasticSlideshow/index2.html

The image resizing works just fine when I'm previewing from my local host, and it works fine in the demo.

But after I upload the files to my server, hosted at Fatcow, the image resizing stops working after the first image. Everything else gets stretched and distorted in the window.

Could anyone help with this?

Here is what I'm working with:
http://thisiskreie.com/gra322/portfolio/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The errors I received included using ; instead of , to separate values.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">` should be

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

I don't know if this is all of your issue, but these are what I witnessed.

Comment: Thanks for finding that. I fixed that, but I'm still having the same problem. It's really the weirdest problem I've ever seen haha.

Answer (score 0):

There can be confliction of `jQuery`

Use `jQuery.noConflict()` to avoid this confliction.

Here is the docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference. I've even uploaded the exact same files to my server from the demo and it won't work. Here is the link: http://thisiskreie.com/ElasticSlideshow/

Comment: Please clear, what problem you are facing? As I tested http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ElasticSlideshow/index2.html and http://thisiskreie.com/ElasticSlideshow/index2.html both are looking similar.

Comment: When the window is resized on  tympanus.net/Tutorials/ElasticSlideshow/index2.html the image resizes with it. On mine, at  thisiskreie.com/ElasticSlideshow/index2.html it is not resizing. It distorts and stretches when the window is resized. But i'm using the same code and I can't seem to find why it won't work.

Comment: Which web browser are you using? I checked in `mozilla` and it works fine.

Comment: Wow you're right. Works fine in Mozilla. I didn't even think to try, sorry about that. Still doesn't work in my Safari or my Chrome though. Interesting.

Comment: I downloaded the source code from http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/21/elastic-image-slideshow-with-thumbnail-preview/ and it is working in my chrome too.

Comment: I downloaded it as well, and it works on my local system. The problem appears when I upload it to my ftp server. Once it's there, I can't get it to work. It seems pretty weird.

Comment: It was just my .htaccess file. It's fixed. THanks!