# Elastic image slideshow don't resize image

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

when I use the elastic image slider I have the same issue as you see at [Elastic Image Slideshow Not Resizing Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127839/elastic-image-slideshow-not-resizing-properly)

When I resize the window on the downloaded example it works fine, but when I try to integrate the plugin using twitter bootstrap, it resize the image's width only.

when I use bootstrap and resize the window the javascript console return this message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
```

And mark the line 32 in file jquery.eislideshow.js:

```
line 32: jQuery.event.handle.apply( context, args );
```

If I resize the window in the example (without making changes), this message doesn't appear.

The first thing I did was add $.noConflict(); and now the image resizing works fine, but the thumbnail control:

1. disaprears using firefox and
2. using chrome the size is too small.

In both cases I cannot change the slide and console error return this message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

Someone have a clue to solve this issue? or $.noConflict() is not a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace jQuery.event.handle.apply( context, args ); with $(this).trigger(event.type, args);